# GET request работает POSTMAN, но в браузере нет

Tags: javascript, https

У меня есть следующая конечная точка: https://test3.jmart.kz/company/v2/my/store-location. Туда нужно передавать такие заголовки: 'User-Id': 11, 'Company-Id': 3. В постмане выдает нужный результат, а в браузере 500 ошибку. Для наглядности, я создала в песочницу [здесь] [1](https://jsfiddle.net/ot4L5hn6/8/) и скрин из постмана с заголовками [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
fetch('https://test3.jmart.kz/company/v2/my/store-location', {
 method: 'GET',
 headers: {
  'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'User-Id': 11,
  'Company-Id': 3
 }
}).then(res => res.json())
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Answer (score 0):

У PHP в массиве на 20й линии нету нулевого элемента. От туда и ошибка.

```
Файл: /var/www/html/project-app/app/V2/Http/Responses/StoreLocation/StoreLocationViewResponse.php
Линия: 20
Ошибка: Undefined offset: 0
```

Скинь кусочек кода, если сам не разберёшься, и я дополню ответ.